# Do Apollo cache resolvers work for aliases?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, graphql-js, apollo-cache-inmemory

Take these queries:

```
query Foo(id: ID!) {
  foo(id: $id) {
    id
    bar {
      id
    }
  }
}

query Bar(id: ID!) {
  bar(id: $id) {
    id
  }
}

query Qux(id: ID!) {
  qux: bar(id: $id) {
    id
  }
}
```

As you can see, `qux` is an alias for `bar`.

And now take these cache redirects:

```js
export default {
  Query: {
    bar: (_, args, { getCacheKey }) => getCacheKey({ __typename: "Bar", id: args.id }),
    qux: (_, args, { getCacheKey }) => getCacheKey({ __typename: "Bar", id: args.id }),
  },
};
```

Does the `qux` resolver work? I'm sure it works for `bar`, because I tried it before, but I couldn't tell whether it worked for `qux` or the data just loaded quickly.

Comment: FWIW, you can verify whether a request was a cache hit or miss by examining the network tab of your browser's dev tools.